# Logic: Subtract Integer from a total Integer

Tags: objective-c, integer, logic

Okay, this may sound a little dumb or probably is easier than I think, but I just can't seem to get around the logic.

So I have 2 int variables.

Integer Variable #1: "substract"
Integer Variable #1: "total"

I have the user input a number, that number should be added to the subtract value and then subtracted to the total.

For example, the user enters: 25 then hits enter.
Then he comes back again and he enters 10.

The total should be showing: -35.

I have tried using some sort of logic to get this working but I can only get it to display the subtract value and it doesn't give me a total. In a another words is not combining the terms to the total.

Any ideas how to get around this issue? Anything to get me on the right track will be very helpful.

For reference, this is the code I am using:

```
    moneySpent = absoluteValue_NoDisplay.floatValue;

    moneyTotal  = -moneySpent;

    overviewOutputCovertionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", moneyTotal];

    overviewOutputLabelTotalMoney.text = overviewOutputCovertionString;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly.  I think you need

```
moneyTotal -=moneySpent;
```

Which means

```
moneyTotal = moneyTotal - moneySpent;
```

Where are you storing the first input 25 and the second input 10?

Comment: 25 and 10 comes from the same input. I used -= and that did the trick. Thank you very much